# How can I import a python module function dynamically?

Tags: python, function, import, module

Assuming `my_function()` is located in my_apps.views I would like to import `my_function` dynamically without using something like `exec` or `eval`.

Is there anyway to accomplish this. I'm looking to do something similar to:

```py
my_function = import_func("my_apps.views.my_function")

my_function()
   ... code is executed
```

Answer (score 35):

you want

```
my_function = getattr(__import__('my_apps.views'), 'my_function')
```

If you happen to know the name of the function at compile time, you can shorten this to

```
my_function = __import__('my_apps.views').my_function
```

This will load `my_apps.views` and then assign its `my_function` attribute to the local `my_function`.

If you are sure that you only want *one* function, than this is acceptable. If you want more than one attribute, you can do:

```
views = __import__('my_apps.views')
my_function = getattr(views, 'my_function')
my_other_function = getattr(views, 'my_other_function')
my_attribute = getattr(views, 'my_attribute')
```

as it is more readable and saves you some calls to `__import__`. again, if you know the names, the code can be shortened as above.

You could also do this with tools from the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module but it's more complicated.

Comment: There will be problems (AttributeError) with the __import__ statements above. Import returns the first module (my_apps) unless an import list is specified. You need something like:
`my_function = __import__('my_apps.views', globals(), locals(), ['my_function']).my_function`
See [python doc about __import__](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

Comment: For me this attempts to import the function from `my_apps` instead of `my_apps.views`.

Comment: @marco Actually __import__('my_apps.views', fromlist=['my_function']).my_function is enough.

Answer (score 9):

Note that `Python 2.7` added the [`importlib` module](http://docs.python.org/library/importlib.html#module-importlib),
convenience wrappers for `__import__()` and a backport of 3.1 feature.

> This module is a minor subset of what is available in the more full-featured package of the same name from Python 3.1 that provides a complete implementation of import. What is here has been provided to help ease in transitioning from 2.7 to 3.1.
>
> `importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`
>
> Import a module. The name argument specifies what module to import in absolute or relative terms (e.g. either pkg.mod or ..mod). If the name is specified in relative terms, then the package argument must be specified to the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name (e.g. import_module('..mod', 'pkg.subpkg') will import pkg.mod). The specified module will be inserted into sys.modules and returned.

Comment: The subset of importlib available in Python 2.7 is also available on PyPI and is backported there to work with Python 2.3 and later.

Answer (score 3):

```
def import_by_string(full_name):
    module_name, unit_name = full_name.rsplit('.', 1)
    return getattr(__import__(module_name, fromlist=['']), unit_name)


exists = import_by_string("os.path.exists")
```

Comment: Since version 2.4 (from 2004), Python has had the function `rsplit()`, it is much more efficient to do `module_name, unit_name = full_name.rsplit('.', 1)`, than what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. Did not think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this code and seems what a lot of people need, so even if later i show it

```
def my_import(module_name,func_names = [],cache = False):
    if module_name in globals() and cache:
        return True
    try: 
        m = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), func_names, -1)
        if func_names:
            for func_name in func_names:
                globals()[func_name] = getattr(m,func_name)
        else:
            globals()[module_name] = m
        return True
    except ImportError:
        return False
def my_imports(modules):
    for module in modules:
        if type(module) is tuple:
            name = module[0]
            funcs = module[1]
        else:
            name = module
            funcs = []
        if not my_import(name, funcs):
             return module
    return ''

def checkPluginsImports(plugin,modules):
    c = my_imports(modules)
    if c:
        print plugin +" has errors!: module '"+c+"' not found"

# example: file test.py with "x" function
def d():
    checkPluginsImports('demoPlugin',[('test',['x'])])

d()
x()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution to this discussion (make sure that the function names are distinct):

```
import importlib
modules = {
            'module1': ('func1', 'func2'),
            'module2': ('func3', 'func4', 'func5')}

imported_func = dict()
for module in modules.keys():
    imported_module = importlib.import_module(module)
    for sub_module in modules[module]:
        imported_func[sub_module] = getattr(imported_module, sub_module)

# Usage
x = imported_func['func1']()    # Insert the required arguments in the parenthesis
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library `pkg_resources`

```
from pkg_resources import EntryPoint
my_function  = EntryPoint.parse("my_function=my_apps.views:my_function").load(require=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have four cases separated by the fact whether the `module` and/or the `function` fixed or not:

1. `module` name is a fixed string, `function` name is a fixed string:

   ```py
   my_function = __import__('my_apps.views', fromlist=['my_function'].my_function
   ```

   (altough in this case it is much more simple to use `from my_app.views import my_function`)
2. `module` name is a fixed string, `function` name is variable:

   ```py
   function_name = ...
   .
   .
   .
   my_function = getattr(__import__('my_apps.views', fromlist=[function_name]),
                         function_name)
   ```
3. `module` name is variable, `function` name is fixed string:

   ```py
   module_name = ...
   .
   .
   .
   my_function = __import__(module_name, fromlist=['my_function']).my_function
   ```
4. `module` name is variable, `function` name is variable:

   ```py
   module_name = ...
   .
   .
   .
   function_name = ...
   .
   .
   .
   my_function = getattr(__import__(module_name, fromlist=[function_name]),
                         function_name)
   ```

Note: For an empty list (that's the default value) as `__import__` keyword argument `fromlist` not the module, but the package root is returned. For all non-empty lists the actual module returned.

Sources and further information:

- [Python documentation -> Built-in Functions -> `__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__)
- [Python documentation -> Built-in Functions -> `getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)