# Import all (*) from dynamic file

Tags: python, django, django-urls, python-import, import-module

I have a package:

```
urls/
    __init__.py
    dev_urls.py
    prod_urls.py
```

This `urls` package is in an app `api` and in my main `urls.py`:

```
...
url(r'^api/v1/', include('apps.api.urls')),
...
```

I know that if I add this to `urls.__init__.py` file:

```
# __init__.py
from dev_urls import *
```

Django will run including `dev_urls.py` as `apps.api.urls`.

But I'd like to make this dynamic by adding a variable in my settings module:

```
# settings
URLS_ENV = 'dev'  # This could be 'prod'
```

Then in my `urls.__init__.py`:

```
# __init__.py
from django.conf import settings
name = settings.URLS_ENV + '_urls'
```

Now, here is the question: How can I do somwthing like:

```
from <name> import *
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but probably having enough information to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/301134/4996248

Comment: @JohnColeman I've read that answer yet. Thank. Note that what I want is to get the functionality to import `apps.api.urls.dev_urls.py` as `apps.api.urls` using `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change the name you import from without changing the filename, the `__name__` property you're probably thinking of is set by how you import it. You would need to use a custom import as John suggested ([see here to import *](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21221452)) or modify the included path as follows

```
...
url(r'^api/v1/', include('apps.api.urls.' + settings.URLS_ENV + '_urls')),
..
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/301139/3945375

This worked for me, this is running:

```
# urls.__init__.py

from django.conf import settings

mod = settings.URL_ENVIRONMENT + '_urls'
exec 'from %s import *' % mod
```